# Merge multiple numeric column as list typed column in data.table [R]

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to find a way to merge multiple column numeric column as a new list type column.

**Data Table**

```
dt <- data.table(
  a=c(1,2,3),
  b=c(4,5,6),
  c=c(7,8,9)
)
```

**Expected Result**

```
   a b c   d
1: 1 4 7 1,4,7
2: 2 5 8 2,5,8
3: 3 6 9 3,6,9
```

**Attempt 1**

I have tried doing append with a list with `dt[,d:=list(c(a,b,c))]` but it just append everything instead and get the incorrect result

```
   a b c       d
1: 1 4 7 1,2,3,4,5,6,...
2: 2 5 8 1,2,3,4,5,6,...
3: 3 6 9 1,2,3,4,5,6,...
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a group by row and place the elements in the `list`

```
dt[, d := .(list(unlist(.SD, recursive = FALSE))), 1:nrow(dt)]
```

-output

```
dt
   a b c     d
1: 1 4 7 1,4,7
2: 2 5 8 2,5,8
3: 3 6 9 3,6,9
```

---

Or another option is `paste` and `strsplit`

```
dt[, d := strsplit(do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep=",")), ",")]
```

---

Or may use `transpose`

```
dt[, d := lapply(data.table::transpose(unname(.SD)), unlist)]
dt
   a b c     d
1: 1 4 7 1,4,7
2: 2 5 8 2,5,8
3: 3 6 9 3,6,9
```

Comment: How can I choose row to group? lets say if I only want to merge a and b instead of a,b,c.

Comment: @IndyZa You can specicy that in `.SDcols` i.e. `dt[, d := lapply(data.table::transpose(unname(.SD)), unlist), .SDcols = a:b]`

Answer (score 1):

```
dt[, d := purrr::pmap(.SD, ~c(...))]
```